# Is it possible to insert into a table variable without defining the schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to insert into a table variable without defining the schema?

I need to do this like

```
Declare @tab1 as table

Insert into @tab1 select * from table2

Select * from @tab1
```

I was trying this query but got error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the first line

*Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'table'.*

Instead of **Declare @tab1 as table** try

> Declare @tab1 as table(col1
>   varchar(100)) i.e. full table schema

e.g.

> Declare @tab1 as table(col1
>   varchar(100))
>
> Insert into @tab1 select [Person Name]
>   from tblInformation
>
> Select * from @tab1

Output:

> **col1**
>
> xyz
>   abc

Answer (score 3):

The error is with this line:

Declare @tab1 as table

> Incorrect syntax near 'table'.

but you have also made a mistake with your insert which should be:

```
select * into tab1
from table2
```

as far as i know you need to declare schema when using table varibles, if you use temp tables you don't so this would work

```
select * into #tab1
from table2
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
declare @tab table (BillID int)
insert into @tab
select top 10 BillID from tblBill
select * from @tab
```

This will not work:

```
select top 10 BillID into @tab from tblBill
select * from @tab
```

If you want to define the schema of the table var on the fly, you can use something like this:

```
declare @str varchar(1000)
set @str = 'declare @tab table (BillID int) ' + 
'insert into @tab ' + 'select top 10 BillID from tblBill ' + 'select * from @tab '
exec(@str)
```

Also, look up ([sp_executesql](http://blog.sqlauthority.com))  on Pinal Dave's site for some good advice